# Read .der file private key C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, cryptography, private-key

```
string LoadPrivateKey = "test.der";

X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(LoadPrivateKey, "test");
```

it is always show "unknown object in factory: DerInteger\r\nParameter name: obj"

I would like to use in the Elliptic Curve Cryptography

how can solve it?

Thank You!

Comment: If I would like to load the .der key file what can I do, Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is your test.der file a binary or pem (text) file?

Comment: This is clearly impossible to answer without the data within `test.der` in question. In your case the constructor you are using is expecting a PKCS#12 key store which includes a private key. But if the `test.der` file only contains the private key it will fail, for instance. So please base 64 encode the test file and include it in your question.

Comment: It is a binary file and it is ECDsa crypto.but the file is .der private key has password. I don't know how to do decode it In .net core. But python has this api https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/ Guys Thank you!

Comment: Which part of including it in your question didn't you understand?

Comment: Finally I solve this problem, When I generate key that select .pfx file. C# process the .pfx is support well.

Comment: .pfx can process ecdsa or rsa ....etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem.

1. Use .pfx include the private key.

2.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("test.pfx", "test");
                ECDsa mECDsa = cert.GetECDsaPrivateKey();
                Console.WriteLine("[ECDsa]: "+  mECDsa.KeySize);
```